# How to set an initial filter for my Json data in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I am having a hard time (many days searching and reading) to set an initial value for my data coming from a rails Json file.

My app is about incident tickets and while I am getting all db entries into a data-ng-repeat, I am not able to set the default view e.g. show only unsolved tickets in the beginning, when you first load the page. I would like also the whole bunch of data to be kept available to be filtered when I call ng-click and various conditions.

ticket_controllers.rb

```
var ticketControllers = angular.module('ticketControllers', []);

ticketControllers
    .controller('ticketListController', ['$scope', 'Ticket', 
        function ($scope, Ticket) {
            $scope.tickets_all = Ticket.query();
            $scope.orderProp = 'opened_date';

            $scope.getAllTickets = function (ticket) {
                return $scope.tickets_all;
            };

            $scope.getClosedTickets = function (ticket) {
                if (ticket.status === 'CL') {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            };

            $scope.getUnsolvedTickets = function (ticket) {
                if (ticket.status === 'IP' || ticket.status === 'WF') {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            };

            $scope.getAbortedTickets = function (ticket) {
                // console.log("Just called" + self.ticket);
                if (ticket.status === 'AB') {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            };

            $scope.styleTicketStatus = function (status) {
                switch (status){
                    case ("IP") : return "ui small circular teal label";   break;
                    case ("WF") : return "ui small circular purple label"; break;
                    case ("CL") : return "ui small circular black label";  break;
                    case ("AB") : return "ui small circular black label";  break;
                    default: break;
                }
            };
        }]);
```

template

```
<table class="ui table raised segment">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="text-center six column wide">Issue</th>
      <th class="text-center">Category</th>
      <th class="text-center">Requester</th>
      <th class="text-center">Pending for</th>
      <th class="text-center">Owner</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="ticket in getAllTickets() | filter : search | filter : statusOrder ">
      <td class="text-center">
        <div>
          <span class="{{styleTicketStatus(ticket.status)}}">
              {{ticket.status}}
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td> 
        <a href="/tickets/{{ticket.id}}" class="ticket_link">{{ticket.issue}} </a>
        <br /><small>{{ticket.explanation}}</small>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ticket.ticket_category.category}}</td>
      <td>{{ticket.user.lastname}}, {{ticket.user.firstname}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ticket.date_opened| date:'MM/dd h:mm'}}</td>
      <td>{{ticket.owner.lastname}}, {{ticket.owner.firstname}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

sidebar (filters..)

```
 <div class="ui ">
   <div class="ui input small fluid">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search in tickets..." class="" ng-model="search.issue" >
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="ui vertical fluid small menu ticket-sidebar">
   <a class="active teal item" ng-click="statusOrder = getUnsolvedTickets">
     My unsolved tickets 
     <div class="ui teal label">{{ (tickets_all | filter:getUnsolvedTickets ).length }}</div>
   </a>
   <a class="item" ng-click="statusOrder = getUnsolvedTickets">
     All unsolved tickets 
     <div class="ui label">{{ (tickets_all | filter:getUnsolvedTickets ).length }}</div>
   </a>
   <a class="item" ng-click="statusOrder = getAbortedTickets">
     Aborted tickets
     <div class="ui label">{{ (tickets_all | filter:getAbortedTickets ).length }}</div>
   </a>
   <a class="item" ng-click="statusOrder = getClosedTickets">
     Closed tickets
     <div class="ui label">{{ (tickets_all | filter:getClosedTickets ).length }}</div>
   </a>
   <a class="item" ng-click="statusOrder = getAllTickets">
     All tickets
     <div class="ui label">{{tickets_all.length}}</div>
   </a>
 </div>
```

Can someone shed a little light on my way ?

Comment: really not clear what your specific issue or question is. We don't know what is or isn't working properly for you

Comment: I want to set $scope.getUnsolvedTickets as the default filter but I want to be able to change filtering later from the sidebar.

Comment: should only have one filter function and change the predicate (argument) instead of trying to make `statusOrder` change to be different functions. The `ng-click` in sidebar would then change that predicate

Comment: how ? this is the question. and also what about the "first time" ?

Comment: if that part isn't clear,  create a custom filter by following the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was (as always) easier than I thought :

I just entered a line before the "}" tag :

```
$scope.statusOrder = $scope.getUnsolvedTickets;
```

so it brings the Unsolved ones after calling the function for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to handle the filtering inside your controller and allow the list to change naturally based on the filtered list.

You can access any of the filters programatically via the [`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) service like this:

```
//Get a reference to the 'filter' Filter
var filterFilter = $filter('filter');

//Execute the filter against a list
var filteredList = filterFilter(list, 'substring');
```

Using this approach gives you much more flexibility in your controller. You can set some options based on user input/action, and then execute all the filters at once, which is more performant than using them in bindings.

You can see this in action below:

```js
(function() {

  function ticketCtrl($filter) {
    var $this = this;

    //Get a reference to the 'filter' Filter
    var filter = $filter('filter');

    //Set the initial filter to status === 'Unresolved'
    changeStatusFilter('Unresolved');

    //Changes the status filter and filters the list
    // based on user input
    function changeStatusFilter(status) {
      //Set the new status filter for use in the UI
      $this.statusFilter = status;

      //If we are viewing all statuses, just copy the
      // original list to the one being bound in the UI
      if (status === 'All') {
        $this.filteredTickets = angular.copy(allTickets);
        return;
      }

      //Set the list being bound in the UI by running
      // it through the 'filter' Filter using a custom
      // predicate that matches on status exactly
      $this.filteredTickets = filter(allTickets, function(ticket) {
        return ticket.status === $this.statusFilter;
      });
    };

    //Create a function that can be used from the UI
    // to determine if a given status matches the
    // currently selected filter
    function isCurrentFilter(status) {
      return $this.statusFilter === status;
    };

    //Because we are using the "Controller as" syntax
    // the entire controller will be bound to the scope.
    // Anything we want to be available to the UI needs
    // to be exposed on the controller. We can do this
    // by adding properties and methods to 'this' which
    // is aliased here using the '$this' variable
    $this.isCurrentFilter = isCurrentFilter;
    $this.changeStatusFilter = changeStatusFilter;
  }

  //Set up our dependencies using the '$inject'
  // notation.
  ticketCtrl.$inject = ['$filter'];

  angular.module('ticket-app', [])
    .controller('ticketCtrl', ticketCtrl);

  //Just some static data for demo purposes
  var allTickets = [{
    number: '1234',
    name: 'Answer Question',
    status: 'Resolved'
  }, {
    number: '3982',
    name: 'Include Snippet',
    status: 'Resolved'
  }, {
    number: '0283',
    name: 'Get Upvotes',
    status: 'Unresolved'
  }, {
    number: '0273',
    name: 'Make Pretty',
    status: 'Resolved'
  }, {
    number: '8902',
    name: 'Mark Accepted',
    status: 'Unresolved'
  }, {
    number: '1908',
    name: 'Solve World Hunger',
    status: 'Unresolved'
  }, {
    number: '7923',
    name: 'Pick up dry cleaning',
    status: 'Unresolved'
  }];


}());
```

```html
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- -->
<div class="container" ng-app="ticket-app" ng-controller="ticketCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li ng-class="{active:ctrl.isCurrentFilter('Unresolved')}">
          <a ng-click="ctrl.changeStatusFilter('Unresolved')" href="">Unresolved</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active:ctrl.isCurrentFilter('Resolved')}">
          <a ng-click="ctrl.changeStatusFilter('Resolved')" href="">Resolved</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active:ctrl.isCurrentFilter('All')}">
          <a ng-click="ctrl.changeStatusFilter('All')" href="">All</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Ticket #</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="ticket in ctrl.filteredTickets">
            <td>{{ticket.number}}</td>
            <td>{{ticket.name}}</td>
            <td>
              <span class="label" ng-class="{'label-success':ticket.status==='Resolved','label-danger':ticket.status==='Unresolved'}">{{ticket.status}}</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's all I want and I appreciate your time but it could be great If I could understand what you do ! I lost you somewhere in angular.copy(allTickets);...

Comment: I suppose that you save the part until "ticketCtrl.$inject = ['$filter'];" in a separate .js file, right ?

Comment: @RobDel - I've added some inline annotations in the code to help explain what is going on.